# How to be alerted of AWS volumes with State=Available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, volume, amazon-ebs

How can I get an email alert when there are 1 or more EBS volumes in AWS with a state of 'Available'?

In AWS we have a team of people who manage EC2 instances. Sometimes instances are deleted and redundant volumes are left, showing as State = Available (seen here https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#Volumes:sort=state).

I would like to be notified by e-mail when this happens, so I can manually review and delete them as required. A scheduled check and alert (e-mail) of once per day would be ok.

I think this should be possible via AWS Cloudwatch, but I can't see how to do it...

Comment: What implementation languages do you know? It would be simple to write a Lambda in Python, for example, that scans the list of volumes and sends an SNS notification (which you could receive via email).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using in an AWS Lambda process:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
sns = boto3.client('sns')

def chk_vols(event, context):
    vol_array = ec2.volumes.all()
    vol_avail = []
    
    for v in vol_array:
        if v.state == 'available':
            vol_avail.append(v.id)
    
    if vol_avail:
        sns.publish(
            TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:<your region>:<your account>:<your topic>',
            Message=str(vol_avail),
            Subject='AWS Volumes Available'
        )
```